# Avoid duplicate inflight messages in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

We are building a system where an external system sends us "Refresh" events. These events tell us to refresh the state of an item identified by the id provided in the RefreshEvent.
We handle these events through a Camel route.
The refresh may go wrong, though. If this is case the event is moved to a "Retry" SEDA queue with appropiate retry/backup setup. However, we may experience multiple "Refresh" event for the same item, while we are unable to fetch the new state.
Ideally we'd like to only have unique itemIds in the Retry queue. The inflight itemIds should be unique.

Is there a way to do this in Camel.

I have looked at the IdempotentConsumer, but that has a scope of all received exchanges, I'm only interested in the current inflight exchanges.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not able to use the [IndempotentConsumer](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/idempotentConsumer-eip.html) pattern, you will have to implement the logic yourself and possible change the Seda endpoint to something more sophisticated.

You could use a message queue supporting JMS selectors or property filtering.
ActiveMQ, to name one, has some [capabilities](https://activemq.apache.org/selectors.html) that could be used in implementing the solution you need.